# what does int* foo (int a) return in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
int* foo(int a)
{
    int b = 5;
    int c = a+b;
    return &c;
}
```

I know that's a horrible code but I dont understand what the errors here. What is int* foo() supposed to return and what does &c mean?

Comment: Put a lot more effort into formatting your questions. Your code returns the address of a  local variable, and thus almost certainly exhibits undefined behaviour. Don't write code like this. And read a book on C++.

Comment: `int *` is a pointer, and `&c` is how you create a pointer to `c`. But SO is not the place to request plain beginner programming lessons fragments.

Comment: pointer and reference operator, look it up

Comment: For further research, you can look at what is "rvalue references" (on how to accomplish what that function tried to do) and "smart pointers" (to properly use pointers nowadays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&c` - Is the address of `c`. `foo` returns a pointer to this local variable - `c`.

This is bad and should not be done - as `c` will be out of scope - hence its address will be invalid

Answer (score 0):

`&` in this context is a unary operator that return the address of the variable. `&c` is so the address of the variable `c`.

`int * foo()` is so returning an address and more accurately the address of an integer variable (`c`);

However, return the address of a local variable is never good because its address will be invalid!

Comment: What  is wrong in my answer for getting downvotes? Thanks for who will explain

Comment: It seem to me that advising to read a good C++ manual to start C++ is a bizarre advice : those are hard to find between the not-so-good one, the ones one should'nt read, and the complex ones, especially when you are inexperienced and/or too young to critically document yourself while looking for a good guide. Furthermore, they usually require some heavy brain effort to understand or sometimes to put in application (install boost to learn c++ is something i've already seen in a so-called beginner's manual), and show poor didactic perspective, which naturally lead to less c++ devloppers.

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume Thanks for the advice. I edited my answer and I'll keep in mind this for future answers. At least, now I know what was wrong!

Comment: still, that is _my_ opinion, and does not stand as std view haha. removing the minus one, out of courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

`int *foo(int a)` is the function signature of foo telling us the parameter is an integer and foo **returns a pointer to an integer**.

`&c` is a reference to the **memory location** where the integer c is stored.

So your function returns a pointer to the memory address at which c is stored.

**Edit**: As noted, since the scope of c is the function `foo()`, the address becomes invalid and foo doesn't return anything of use